# Изменение ссылки плагина WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, плагин

Стоит плагин **another-wordpress-classifieds-plugin**. при заходе просмотра анонса `url` выглядит вот так: `http://www.site.nu/another-wordpress-classifieds-plugin/show-ad/?id=193`.

Вопрос. Можно ли `/another-wordpress-classifieds-plugin/` изменить на другое или короткое, к примеру `/awcp/`?

Answer (score 0):

Так он сам сейчас так выводит:

при попытке набрать https://kagg.eu/another-wordpress-classifieds-plugin/show-ad/?id=1

получаем https://kagg.eu/awpcp/show-ad/?id=1

Comment: странно. у меня такого нет.

Comment: Возможно, версия плагина нуждается в обновлении. Я скачал и поставил сегодня.

Comment: удалил плагин. поставил заново. не заменяется. с чем может быть связано?

Comment: скорее всего, все ссылки уже прописаны в базе для ранее созданных объектов.